# What is the difference between accessibilityLabel and aria-label properties of view component in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, accessibility

What is the difference between accessibilityLabel and aria-label properties of view component in react native? React native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#accessibilitylabel) is not enough to understand. Examples would be more appreciated.

Comment: check these docs instead of react native ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is they are the same thing but `accessibilityLabel` is used for native mobile apps and `aria-label` is used for web/HTML apps.

They both will override the [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name) of an element.

You typically only need to override the label if the contents of that element doesn't provide enough context or detail.

For example, if you have a button that contains an image but no text (eg, a print icon), then that button will need a "print" label.  If you're creating a native app, you'd set the `accessibilityLabel` attribute. If you're creating a website, you'd set the `aria-label` attribute.

Comment: So you mean accessibilityValue and aria-valuemax, aria-valuemin, aria-valuenow, aria-valuetext are worked as same as accessibilityLabel and aria-label right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The doc for [accessibilityValue](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#accessibilityvalue) even talks about max, min, and current value.

Comment: I'm now wondering how aria-labelledby fits into this because aria-labelledby overrides/masks aria-label.

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant. The OP was asking about native app development, using react native, and it has an attribute that is similar to aria-label.  I don't think there's an aria-labelledby equivalent for native apps.